# Portlet URL appending Session ID?

Tags: java, portlet, portal

I'm facing a problem and don't know if it is even possible, what I'm trying to do: I just want to append my session ID to all my URLs which are generated in my portal?

I'm using JSR-268 Portlets and tried to define a public-render-parameter - if I'm not wrong, this should be - once set - available to all other portlets which support this parameter. Sadly it isn't that case. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Portlet 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286):

> Public render parameters are intended for sharing view state across portlets.

This suggests that you are correct (though whether the parameter is actually visible in the browser URL would be implementation detail). I would recheck your `portlet.xml` settings and how you set/get the parameters against the details listed in *PLT.11.1.2 Public Render Parameters* of the [spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286).

*(I'm not sure why you would want to pass around your session ID, but that is another matter.)*